# how to call function on window close in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, popup, angular2-forms

```
oauthLogin(app) {
    this.openAuthPopup(
      '/assets/auth.html?socialApp=' + app, () => {
        if (this.SharedService.getAuthorization()) {
          this.checkRegistrationStatus();
          this.SharedService.changeLoggedInStatus(true);
          this.SharedService.changedisplayName(this.SharedService.getDispalyName());
          this.router.navigate(['home/dashboard']); 
        }
      }
    );
}
```

my popup window opening code

```
openAuthPopup(url, callback) {
    window.open(url, '_blank');
    callback();
  }
```

i have created this function and calling this function from html. This function is opening a popup tab. I want such that my if condition to be checked as my popup tab get closed, but currently what is happening is like my if condition is checked during the processes on popup tab.
I am stucked. Help needed.

thanks in advance

Comment: register a window event

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to listen to the event `beforeunload` with `HostListener` from Angular

```
@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
beforeunloadHandler(event) {
    // actions
}
```